# RHEL - tcp_delack_min sysctl parameter missing on realtime kernels

Tags: linux, tcp, tuning, realtime

I'm looking to modify the tcp_delack_min sysctl tunable on several RHEL/CentOS systems. It should be located at `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_delack_min`. I'm finding that it is missing in recent kernels. While the parameter is available on `2.6.24.7-161`, I do not see it in `2.6.33.7-rt29.47.el5rt`. This may help a networking issue we're experiencing, and the [RHEL MRG documentation clearly notes this function](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_MRG/1.3/html/Realtime_Tuning_Guide/sect-Realtime_Tuning_Guide-General_System_Tuning-Reducing_the_TCP_delayed_ack_timeout.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've heard back from Red Hat on this. The patch providing this feature is the `bz460217-nagle-tunables.patch`. It is no longer part of the RHEL MRG 1.3 kernel, but will be added to the next update of the RHEL MRG 2.0 kernel.

Comments from the patch:

```
Make ato min and delack min tunable 
This might potentially help with some programs which have problems with nagle. 
Sockets have to be restarted
```